# Keep owners of files from tar file after un-archiving in Gradle task

Tags: linux, gradle, tar

I have a tar.gz file, which is created with the command: 
`tar -czvpf file.tar.gz my_directory`
So files' permissions and owners should be saved there.

If I call un-tar command line directly in the terminal (under the root), files' permissions and owners are okay:

```
tar --same-owner -xvf file.tar -C /target/directory
```

^ this produces correct results in un-archived folders structure.

I also have a Gradle task which is supposed to un-tar this file to a destination folder:

```
task unTarPredefinedProjectTree(type:Exec) {
    workingDir envDumpDir
    commandLine ('tar --same-owner -xvf file.tar.gz -C /target/directory')
}
```

The problem is: when I call gradle task from the same terminal:

```
gradle unTarPredefinedProjectTree
```

All files' owners get reset to root.

I tried putting command line arguments separately:

```
commandLine ('tar', '--same-owner', '-xvf', 'file.tar.gz', '-C', '/target/directory')
```

And tried using tarTree function:

```
task unTarPredefinedProjectTree << {
    copy {
        from tarTree(file('file.tar.gz'))
        into '/target/directory'
    }
}
```

Still the same: 'root' owner after using Gradle task, but correct owners after calling the command manually in the terminal. The same terminal's window and I'm under the root user in both cases.

So how to force Gradle to keep tar file's owners?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the original user of the file ? Which user is running `gradle` ?

Comment: In both cases I'm running under 'root' user. `root: tar --same-owner -xvf file.tar -C /target/directory` and `root: gradle unTarPredefinedProjectTree`

Comment: I tried to reproduce but no luck, it's ok for me, even `gradle` keeps original file's owners.